# Understanding Recoil and the Effect of Mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I was hoping someone could help me understand recoil properties of a handgun a bit better. I have read several threads here and a bunch of random websites and I don't feel like they are all necessarily correct or in agreement. Using an example of a Glock 17 since the numbers are convenient, a Glock 17 fires a bullet with a muzzle energy of 650J so that means that there should be a force of 650J going in the opposite direction acting on the slide. A Glock 17's recoil spring travels 50mm before bottoming out and takes 75N of energy to fully compress so the spring constant would be 1520 Nm and given the potential energy equation for springs, it could only absorb 2J of recoil so the amount of energy imparted on the shooter when the slide bottoms out will be 648J of recoil. My confusion, I think at least, is whether the mass of the slide makes any difference to the recoil characteristics. It seems to me that the amount of recoil energy that needs to be absorbed by the shooter is the same regardless of whether slide has a large mass or small mass. The velocity of the slide may vary depending on the mass of the slide (0.5kg mass of slide from the factory), but since it's the same amount of energy and kinetic energy initial is equal to kinetic energy final (ignoring friction), it should be the same. I saw other threads discuss momentum in this discussion rather than kinetic energy but I'm not sure if this is needed.

One thread here suggested that the higher mass would mean a slower velocity so the force applied to the shooter would be spread out over a greater amount of time. If I understand that correctly, it would mean that the 648J would be dispersed over a greater amount of time so the peak impulse would be less. Given that the recoil spring absorbs very little energy and all remaining energy would be transferred when the slide/spring bottom out, wouldn't it basically just be ever so slightly shifting when the recoil is felt rather than attenuating the peak force?

Respectfully,

Nate

Comment: The _impulse_ (change in momentum) that is imparted to the bullet will be equal to the impulse imparted to the pistol and the hand that holds it, but the _energy_ that is carried away by the bullet is _not_ equal to the energy that is absorbed by the action and the hand.

Answer (score 0):

> a Glock 17 fires a bullet with a muzzle energy of 650J

I am not familiar with that pistol so I will take your value as gospel.

> a force of 650J going in the opposite direction

Forces are measured in Newtons, not Joules.

> A Glock 17's recoil spring travels 50mm before bottoming out

Again, taken as gospel.

> takes 75N of energy to fully compress

Energy is measured in Joules, not Newtons. I will assume that you mean a force here. I check this assumption right away in the next bit.

> so the spring constant would be 1520 Nm

$$\tag1F=kx\quad\implies\quad k=\frac Fx=\frac{75\,\text N}{50\,\text{mm}}\left(\frac{1000\,\text{mm}}{\text m}\right)=1500\,\text{N/m}\approx1520\,\text{N/m}$$
which means that I simultaneously deduce that you meant a force above, as assumed, and the spring constant units are N/m not Nm, likely a typo on your part.

> it could only absorb 2J of recoil

$$\tag2\frac12kx^2=1.9\,\text J\approx2\,\text J$$
so yes, this is correct.

> I saw other threads discuss momentum in this discussion rather than kinetic energy but I'm not sure if this is needed.

This is absolutely crucial, and it is between the interplay of energy and momentum considerations that mass will come in. Indeed, the previous statement of yours is

> since it's the same amount of energy and kinetic energy initial is equal to kinetic energy final (ignoring friction), it should be the same.

Yes, there is a set amount of energy being given. However, the kinetic energy distributed over all the entities involved is very different. Momentum and mass enter into the considerations.

---

Over the analysis of your question, it is extremely clear that you are very confused over forces, energies, momentum, and so forth. With a foundation that is shaky, it is difficult to explain to you why the mass would even matter. There are no lack of good explanations out there, but you also have to be able to be precise over what is happening, starting from the language used. This is part of why physicists love to have algebraic quantities written out; they help us clearly delineate what quantities referred to are forces, what are energies, and what are momenta. Then the analysis of the actual problem at hand becomes possible.

For example, you have missed out talking about the mass of the bullet. Do you know that this is extremely important too? Rather, the ratio of the masses of the bullet and the pistol. For simplicity, not including the mass of the slide, or assuming that there is no slide, or something.

Comment: Thank you for your comment